# How to create object from pointer to object without copy initialization?

Tags: c++

User creates as many objects as he wants and the program links them with pointers. 1st node's `ptrTo` is equal to 2nd node's `this` pointer.

I have a function and one of its parameter is reference to `LinkNode` object named with `r_node`. I cannot `use r_node` directly because statements like `r_node = r_node.forward()` don't work like I want (because references cannot be assigned to, this statement does copy what's in `r_node.forward()` to itself, doesn't forward.). I don't want to use `nodeptr` because I've used `node` (object) a lot of times (hundreds) and as you can see, forward does not return pointer type. I cannot change forward function or implement another member function, sorry.

`LinkNode node = *nodeptr` or `LinkNode node = r_node` : It is copy initialization, I want the real one (what I created in main.cpp). This is because `ptrTo` is linking with next object's this pointer. I actually have a lot of functions like removing, adding nodes etc. So this cannot be solution.

`LinkNode& node = *nodeptr` or `LinkNode& node = r_node` : Because references cannot be assigned to, `node = node.forward()` doesn't work.

**Interface.cpp**

```
#include "node.h"

void Interface(LinkNode& r_node){

    LinkNode* nodeptr = &r_node;
    // I want to create node object from nodeptr (or r_node) here.
    
    node=node.forward();
    
}
```

**node.h**

```
#pragma once

class LinkNode{
    
    private:

        std::string payload="";
        LinkNode* ptrTo = nullptr;
        LinkNode* ptrBack = nullptr;
    
    public:

        LinkNode(std::string payload=""){ this->payload=payload; }

        ~LinkNode(){}

        LinkNode* getPtr()        { return this; }

        void setPtrTo   (LinkNode* ptr){ ptrTo = ptr; }
        void setPtrBack (LinkNode* ptr){ ptrBack = ptr; }

        LinkNode& forward()  { return *ptrTo; }
        LinkNode& backward() { return *ptrBack; }
        
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"

void Interface(LinkNode& node);

int main(){

    int lengthofLink=0;
    std::cout<<"Submit your length of link: "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>lengthofLink;

    LinkNode** array{ new LinkNode* [lengthofLink]{} };

    /* Payloads of nodes determining and pointer to classes are putting into array. */

    for(int i=0;i<lengthofLink;i++){ 
        std::string data;
        std::cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<". payload: ";
        std::cin>>data;
        array[i] = new LinkNode (data); //array[i] holds the pointer that new gives.
    }

    for(int i=0; i<lengthofLink-1; i++){ // Place of forward linking
        LinkNode* t_ptr_f = array[i+1]->getPtr();
        array[i]->setPtrTo(t_ptr_f); 
    }

    for(int i=lengthofLink; i>=2 ; i--){ // Place of backward linking
        LinkNode* t_ptr_b = array[i-2]->getPtr();
        array[i-1]->setPtrBack(t_ptr_b);
    }

    LinkNode& r_node = *(array[0]);

    Interface(r_node);

    // Deleting parts, unnecessary for you

    for(int i=0;i<lengthofLink;i++){ 
        delete array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

It is not important if you find the solution dynamically allocated way or not. I am new to C++. Thanks for advance!

Comment: In C++ objects cannot appear out of thin air. A new objects must be constructed, in some form or fashion. If there's an existing object then a reference or a pointer to the object can be used, until that object no longer exists. This is how objects work in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If a function isn't inlined a reference is simply a (constant) pointer under the hood, using pointers is almost the same in terms of the machine code generated by the compiler, simply a pointer on the stack.

making `node` a pointer makes more sense, as it is not a const pointer but a variable one.

```cpp
LinkNode* node = nodeptr; // copy the pointer to give it a first value

node = &(node->forward()) // make it a pointer to the next item.
```

The last line can be repeated until you reach the end of the structure.

If you don't like the syntax of dereferencing a pointer then you can create another class that will hold that pointer and just overload the assignment operator to do the dereferencing, but overall it's the same code, just fancier.